# Sharepoint 2010 Updating fields on XsltListViewWebPart view giving error adding a field using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

scenario:
we have two fields that were added to the Shared Documents library default view "All Documents".  The shared Documents XsltListViewWebPart view on the home.aspx page does not reflect the changes because this existed OOTB.  I need to add the two fields to the XsltListViewWebPart view because several sites already exist and a manual change is out of the question.

I have found a resource that deletes all the ViewFields for the XsltListViewWebPart and then adds the fields from the view of the library.
http://spblog.net/post/2011/04/26/Changing-default-view-for-ListViewWebPart-programmatically.aspx

I had to modify it to work in my environment a little, but here is the source

```
# Add SharePoint cmdlets reference
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://myServer/sites/Test_Site04_18_03-03-49"
$file = $web.GetFile("SitePages/Home.aspx");
$wpMngr = $file.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.Webparts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);
$sharedDocList = $web.Lists["Shared Documents"]
$sharedDocViewFields = $list.Views["All Documents"].ViewFields
$foundWebPart = $false

:webPartLoop foreach($webPart in $wpMngr.WebParts)
{
    :viewLoop foreach($view in $sharedDocList.Views)
    {
        if($webPart.ViewGuid -eq $view.ID.ToString("B"))
        {
            $foundWebPart = $true

            $view.ViewFields.DeleteAll()

            #loop through all the fields in the shared doc view and add them
            foreach($field in $sharedDocViewFields)
            {
                write-host "field: " $field
                $view.ViewFields.Add($field)
            }

            $view.Update();
            break viewLoop
        }
    }

    #break out of the loop because we already found the webpart and modified the view
    if ($foundWebPart)
    {
        break webPartLoop
    }
}
```

i run it and see an error:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Column 'ColumnName' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."
+ $view.ViewFields.Add <<<< ($field)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

what am i doing wrong?  I think there might be an issue with how the original field on the Doc Lib.  Very strange that i can write it out to the screen but it is telling it doesn't exist when i try to add it to the new view.
I even tried approaching this from the point of just changing the view to the same view used by the library, but had no success.  An article i was reading mentioned something about hidden views.....